# Declaring a struct in a header makes it global

Tags: c, header, struct, global

There are three files:
source1.c
source2.c
header.h

The two source-files includes the header.

This is the code of the header:

```
struct
{
    int a;
    int b
} x;
```

What happens now is that the struct becomes global and the two source-files now shares the struct called x. Why does this happen?

I know that if you write the following code it will make two global variables. One for each of the source-files. (they don't share the globals)

```
int x = 0;
```

The last piece of code makes sense to me but i really don't understand the one with the struct..

EDIT:
Hmm everybody here think I should get linker errors. My current code is for an embedded system (nxtOSEK). I'll try to convert it to a regular C program later.

EDITEDIT:
I'm back with examples in regular C. As you can see it is not only possible with structs but also with regular variables.

source1.c

```
#include "header.h"

int main(void)
{
    f();
    x = 1;
    f();
}
```

source2.c

```
#include "header.h"

void f()
{
    printf("source2: %i\n", x);
}
```

header.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x;
```

Output

```
source2: 0
source2: 1
```

Note that x must not be declared for it to work or it gives a linker error like everyone here said. (I don't know why it work with the embeded system..)

It also looks like I misread Eric Postpischil's answer which looks correct.

Comment: "I know that if you write the following code it will make two global variables. One for each of the source-files". No, it won't.

Comment: Well, that is what happens.. Imagine that source1.c is updating x regularly and they both print the current value. You will see that the value in source2.c is never updated.

Comment: You need to show compilabe code for all three files then (with the struct and with the int), and the command(s) you used to compile them. Because you aren't doing what I think you're doing. What I think you're doing in the `int` case results in a linker error. And apparently you aren't doing what either of the answerers think you're doing either, because they also both disagree with you what causes linker errors and what doesn't.

Comment: Use a debugger - single step through the code and you shall enter the 'Matrix' - it will be clear -- crystal clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An external declaration of an object identifier at file scope that has an initializer is a *definition*. The declaration `int x = 0;` is a definition because `x` is initialized.

An external declaration of an object identifier at file scope that does not have an initializer is a *tentative definition*. The declaration `struct {…} x;` is a tentative definition because `x` is not initialized.

Multiple definitions at link time cause an error.

Multiple tentative definitions at link time may be coalesced to a single definition, which is initialized with zero. This was traditional Unix behavior and was the default behavior with GCC prior to version 10; GCC marked tentative definitions as “common” symbols by default. With GCC version 10 and later, multiple-definition errors may result. The old behavior can be selected with the `-fcommon` command-line switch to GCC.

If you change `int x = 0;` to `int x;`, you will not a get a link error while using build tools that treat tentative definitions as common symbols. If you change `struct {…} x;` to `struct {…} x = {0};`, you will get a link error.

Answer (score 9):

The piece of code below

```
struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} x;
```

declares a variable `x` of type `struct` with no tag. This is OK for a static struct that you plan to use in a single compilation unit, but if you plan to share a `struct` among several .c files, you should not do it like that. Instead, you should define a tag for your `struct` or make a `typedef` for it, and declare the variable of that type separately, using the `srtruct my_struct` syntax.

Here is an example:

Put this `struct` declaration in the header:

```
struct a_and_b
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Put this variable declaration in the .c file:

```
static struct a_and_b x;
```

Now `x` is no longer global: you can access it inside your .c file, but it is not visible from the outside. If you want to make it global, but avoid linker errors, add

```
extern struct a_and_b x;
```

to the header, and remove `static` from the declaration in the .c file.

Comment: I know that you could do that to create a struct definition which is shared between the .c files, but my question is why my struct variable becomes global and whether that would be a valid way to make global struct variables.

Comment: @SamOlesen Your structure becomes global because its declaration gets inserted verbatim into every .c file that includes your header. This is **not** a valid way of making a global structure: if you include the header with such declaration from several .c files, you would get linker errors because of multiple definitions of `x`.

Comment: No, that is the strange part. I don't get any linker errors.
I do if I write the following in my header:
    int x = 0;

Comment: hmm just tested again with int x = 0; It doesn't make linker errors. My bad. But that makes sense because the source files shouldn't know about each others variable in the header-file. Therefore no conflicts. But that doesn't explain why my struct variable becomes global.

Comment: @SamOlesen That's the thing: the variable is *not* in the header file as far as the compiler is concerned; it is in the header only for the preprocessor - the compiler sees the definition copied verbatim into the body of your .c file, so if you include the same header with `int x=0;` in several .c files that you compile together, you will definitely see a linker error. Of course you wouldn't see linker errors if you compile these files separately, and do not link them together.

Comment: See my previous comment. Sorry for my confusion ;)

Comment: The files are compiled into a single executable.

Comment: @SamOlesen That is very strange. Could you please update your question with the makefile or the command line that you use to build the two files? You should be getting a linker error in both these cases.